# canot restore disk image with dd (target part filled with zero)

Tags: linux, backup, dd, gzip

I have a RAID0 disk before, now I want change the size of it.

From the manual, the only way is backup data, delete RAID, re-create with new size, and restore data.

now I have many old 2.5" hdd, each has "small" free space. so I want backup each RAID-partition to a disk. then restore them.

I used this command to backup a single partition:

`dd if=/dev/md126p1 conv=sync bs=32M | gzip -c2 > /mnt/backup1/windowsD.img.gz`

then I re-create RAID, restore partitions with exactly same geometry.

write back the image:

`gunzip -c /mnt/backup1/windowsD.img.gz | dd of=/dev/md126p1 conv=sync bs=32M`

the result is

- I can't mount this partition.
- gparted know this partition is NTFS.
- many zero-byte filled in dest-partition.

Who ever know what happend..... I will cry if these data lose....T_T

I try do find something with this:

> cat /dev/md126p1 | head -c 5M > /tmp/c
>
> gunzip -c windowsD.img.gz | head -c 5M > /tmp/b
>
> vbindiff /dev/a /tmp/b

that shows me, the start of file a&b is same, but then there is many many zero in file a.